# A simple question regarding AR(1) process and CDFs

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-process, autoregressive, joint-distribution, independence

Somewhat a trivial question, but I struggle to get my head around it. Consider we have an AR(1) process, as follows:

$y_t=\rho y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,\quad t=1,...,T$.

such that $\varepsilon_t$ are $i.i.d$ and $\varepsilon_t\sim N(0,1)$. Evidently, $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ are correlated and as such a joint probability, such as $P[y_t\leq0,y_{t-1}\leq 0]\neq P[y_{t}\leq 0]P[y_{t-1}\leq0]$.

But given that $y_t=\rho y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ and $y_{t-1}=\rho y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}$, the aforementioned joint probability can be manipulated and expressed as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
P[y_t\leq0,y_{t-1}\leq 0]&=&P[\rho y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\leq 0,\rho y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}\leq 0]\\
&=&P[\varepsilon_t\leq-\rho y_{t-1},\varepsilon_{t-1}\leq-\rho y_{t-2}]
\end{eqnarray}
But from earlier, we know that $\varepsilon_1,...,\varepsilon_t$ are $i.i.d$ implying that
\begin{eqnarray}
P[\varepsilon_t\leq-\rho y_{t-1},\varepsilon_{t-1}\leq-\rho y_{t-2}]&=&P[\varepsilon_t\leq-\rho y_{t-1}]P[\varepsilon_{t-1}\leq-\rho y_{t-2}]\\
&=&P[y_t\leq0][y_{t-1}\leq0]
\end{eqnarray}
which is obviously in contradiction with the earlier results. I know I am missing a step here, so some clarification would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The conclusion after "implying that" appears to assume $y_{t-1}$ and $y_{t-2}$ are independent of each other and of $\varepsilon_t$ and $\varepsilon_{t-1}.$  Is that the case?  If not, what is your justification for it?

Comment: I am rather confused. Clearly in and AR(1) process, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not independent. Hence, as mentioned earlier $P[y_{t-1}\leq 0,y_{t-2}\leq 0]\neq P[y_{t-1}\leq 0]P[y_{t-2}\leq 0]$. However, my point is if the inequalities in the joint probability are expressed in terms of the residuals, and we already know that the residuals are independent, then $P[\varepsilon_{t}\leq -\rho y_{t-1},\varepsilon_{t-1}\leq -\rho y_{t-2}]=P[\varepsilon_{t}\leq -\rho y_{t-1}]P[\varepsilon_{t-1}\leq -\rho y_{t-2}]$. Is that not the case? Or is my question still ambiguous?

Comment: @Carl: in your $\epsilon$ equation, rhs of the inequality is not a constant but a random variable itself, so just because LHS is iid you cannot split it as you have.

Comment: @Dayne What do you exacly imply by not splitting? So suppose you have expressed $P[y_{t-1}\leq0,y_{t-2}\leq0]$ in terms of residuals as I have. Do you imply that if I were to express the probabilities as bivariate normal CDFs, the covariance matrix should contain non-zero off-diagonal elements (i.e. implying correlation of the residuals)?

Comment: @Carl let me put it this way: let $A, B, C, D$ be four random variables such that $A, B$ are independent and $C, D$ are not. Clearly, $Pr(A<a, B<b)=Pr(A<a)Pr(B<b) \forall a,b \in \mathbb R$. However, do you think the following is also true?  $Pr(A<C, B<D)=Pr(A<C)Pr(B<D)$. I think not as now your random variables become $A-C$ and $B-D$ which are not independent.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a fixed initial value $y_0\in\mathbb R$, we have $y_t = \rho^t y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^t\rho^{i-1}\varepsilon_t$ for $t=1,2,\ldots,T$. Note that the linear combination of independent normal random variables is again normal, so $\sum_{i=1}^t\rho^{i-1} \varepsilon_t$ has $N\left(0,\frac{1-\rho^{2(t-1)}}{1-\rho^2}\right)$ distribution. For any $t\in\{1,2,\ldots,T\}$ we may compute the joint distribution of $(y_t,y_{t-1})$ by
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(y_t\leqslant u, y_{t-1}\leqslant v) &= \mathbb P\left(\rho^ty_0 + \sum_{i=1}^t \rho^{t-i}\varepsilon_i\leqslant u, \rho^ty_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \rho^{t-i}\varepsilon_i \leqslant v\right)\\
&= \mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^t \rho^{t-i}\varepsilon_i\leqslant u-\rho^ty_0, \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \rho^{t-i}\varepsilon_i\leqslant v-\rho^ty_0, \right)\\
&= \mathbb P\left(\varepsilon_t+ \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \rho^{t-i}\varepsilon_i\leqslant s-\rho^ty_0, \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \rho^{t-i}\varepsilon_i\leqslant v-\rho^ty_0 \right).
\end{align}